# Hardcoding query params in python requests URL gives different result to key value pair in params

Tags: python, api, rest, python-requests

I am trying to use query parameters in an API. If I hardcode the query parameters, I get the expected results of top 2:

```
requests.get('https://someurl/Counties?$top=2')
```

But if I try

```
q = {"top":"2"}
requests.get('https://someurl/Counties', params=q)
```

I get the default response, with all items and not just the two first. When I try the same approach on a different API, both approaches work. The api uses Odata, if that matters. But I can't get my head around how these two should yield different results in the request that is posted.

Comment: Shouldn't the `q` be `{"$top":"2"}`? Note the `$`

Comment: Yes, that is it. I was mixing up & and $ in the urls I experimented with

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing a dollar sign in front of top.

```
q = {"$top":"2"}
```